# Selecting the "What" field in a Task using an SOQL request

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I'm looking for a way to do a SOQL request to get a Task record, but I keep ending up with this error:

> Error: Compile Error: No such column 'What' on entity 'Task'. If you
>   are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names. at line 59 column 25

The 'What' field is labeled as 'Related To' (it's a standard field of the Activity object).

Here's my request generating this error:

```
Task task = [SELECT Type FROM Task WHERE What = :this.person.Id];
```

Thanks for your solutions.

Comment: if techtrekker's answer worked for you please upvote it or select it as the selected answer if you are able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relationship is called What, to compare with the Id, use WhatId

```
Task task = [SELECT Type FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :this.person.Id];
```

You could also use

```
Task task = [SELECT Type FROM Task WHERE What.Id = :this.person.Id];
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Is it the same thing with `RecordType` ?

Comment: Yes RecordTypeId or RecordType.Id

Comment: To determine this in the future for any object or field try exploring the Salesforce schema with the Force.com explorer http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/ForceExplorer

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here as well - there were some updates in winter 13 that expanded this functionality:
[SOQL Polymorphism](http://blogs.developerforce.com/tech-pubs/2012/09/soql-polymorphism-or-how-i-learned-to-love-the-polymorphic-relationship.html)